# Why isn't my CSS/ Javascript animation working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I am making an animation menu in CSS and Javascript and am having issues with it. The idea is to have a menu with opacity:0 (using CSS) at first then by clicking on the hamburger menu the opacity becomes 1 and the menu slides in to the right a little (using Javascript).The menu flies in fine, but upon clicking the hamburger X button, it doesnt fly out again and the X doesnt change to hamburger icon.

This is a CSS animation (would a transition be easier?)

Here is the code:

```js
let d = document.getElementsByClassName("show")[0];
let f = document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0];
let o = document.getElementsByClassName("burger")[0];
let p = document.getElementsByClassName("burgers")[0];

d.toggleStatus = "off";

f.onclick = function() {
  switch (d.toggleStatus) {
    case "off":
      d.toggleStatus = "on";
      d.setAttribute('style', 'animation-play-state:running');
      break;

    case "on":
      d.toggleStatus = "off";
      d.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
      break;
  }
  o.classList.toggle('rotate');
  p.classList.toggle('rotate2');

}
```

```css
.show {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: menu .3s ease-out;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

@keyframes menu {
  0% {
    margin-right: 190px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 89px;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="burger"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50" /></div>
  <div class="burgers"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50" /></div>
</div>
<div class="show pt-20 min-w-screen text-center min-h-screen">
  <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Work</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
</div>
```

Please view the page on full screen.

Comment: Can you share also your keyframes? maybe in a [mcve]

Comment: First of, don't use setAttribute style, rather use the preferred classList.toggle

Comment: your dfop variables are error prone

Comment: And if I have to mention, if you use the classList.toggle, you won't need the keyframes. Just an .is-active class in CSS that does the transition magic

Comment: I think you were just missing keyframes and rest of code working fine.

Comment: no, the keyframes doesnt reverse the animation when clicking one hamburger menu again. The X on hamburger doesnt toggle again afterwards too

Answer (score 0):

You could use `transition` along with class toggling.

```js
const d = document.querySelector(".menu");
const f = document.querySelector(".burger-container");
const o = document.querySelector(".burger");
const p = document.querySelector(".burgers");

f.addEventListener('click', function() {
  d.classList.toggle('show');
  o.classList.toggle('hidden');
  p.classList.toggle('hidden');
  o.classList.toggle('rotate');
  p.classList.toggle('rotate2');
});

console.clear();
```

```css
.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  margin-right: 190px;
}
.menu.show {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-right: 89px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
<div class="burger-container">
  <div class="burger"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50" /></div>
  <div class="burgers hidden"><img src="https://picsum.photos/40" /></div>
</div>
<div class="menu pt-20 min-w-screen text-center min-h-screen">
  <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Work</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
</div>
```